# Pagination fetching all records without filtering in YII

Tags: php, yii

I am new to Yii. I have done a normal criteria search, and rendering them in the Grid view in Yii. If I click on the second page after searching/filtering, it again gives me the whole set of records in the Grid view.

My View:

```
<div class="form">
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'nimsoft-alerts-form',
    // Please note: When you enable ajax validation, make sure the corresponding
    // controller action is handling ajax validation correctly.
    // There is a call to performAjaxValidation() commented in generated controller code.
    // See class documentation of CActiveForm for details on this.
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
)); ?>

<h1>Missing Hosts List</h1>
<?php //echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>
<div style="float:left;">
    <div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'host_start_date'); ?>
    <?php
        Yii::import('application.extensions.CJuiDateTimePicker.CJuiDateTimePicker');
        $this->widget('CJuiDateTimePicker', array(
            'attribute' => 'host_start_date',
            'language' => '',
            'model' => $model,
            'options' => array(
                'mode' => 'focus',
                'dateFormat' => 'yy-mm-dd',
                //'minDate'=>'0',
                'showAnim' => 'slideDown',
            ),
            'htmlOptions' => array(
                'style'=>'height:20px;',
                'value' => $model->host_start_date,
            ),
        ));
    ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'host_start_date'); ?>      
    </div>
</div>
<div style="float:left;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
<div style="float:left;">
    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'host_end_date'); ?>
        <?php
            Yii::import('application.extensions.CJuiDateTimePicker.CJuiDateTimePicker');
            $this->widget('CJuiDateTimePicker', array(
                'attribute' => 'host_end_date',
                'language' => '',
                'model' => $model,
                'options' => array(
                'mode' => 'focus',
                'dateFormat' => 'yy-mm-dd',
                //'minDate'=>'0',
                'showAnim' => 'slideDown',
                ),
                'htmlOptions' => array(
                    'style'=>'height:20px;',
                    'value' => $model->host_end_date, 
                ),
            ));
        ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'host_end_date'); ?>      
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row buttons">
    <?php echo CHtml::button('Search',array('submit' => array('Site/index')));?>
    <?php echo CHtml::button('Search and Export',array('submit' => array('Site/Export')));?>
</div>


<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<!--<div class="row buttons">  
    <a href="<?php //echo $this->createUrl('Site/Index',array('id'=>$cust_id,'isXLSDownload'=>1));?>" title="Export For All Customers" class="btn btn-primary circle_ok" style="text-decoration: none; color:#FF3333;" ><b>Export All</b></a>
 </div>-->
<?php 
    $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
        'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
        'enableSorting' => false,
        'columns'=>array(
            array(            // display 'create_time' using an expression
                'name'=>'alert_device',
                'value'=>'$data->alert_device',
            ),
            array(            // display 'create_time' using an expression
                'name'=>'alert_event_time',
                'value'=>'$data->alert_event_time',
            ),
            array(            // display 'create_time' using an expression
                'name'=>'alert_datetime',
                'value'=>'$data->alert_datetime',
            ),
        ),
    //'itemView'=>'_view',
    ));     
?>
</div>
```

My Action:

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    //$this->layout=false;
    $model=new NimsoftAlerts;
    if(isset($_POST['NimsoftAlerts']))
    {

        $model->attributes=$_POST['NimsoftAlerts'];
        if($model->validate())
        { 
            $pagination=1;
            $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
            $criteria->condition = "alert_datetime  >= '$model->host_start_date' and alert_datetime <= '$model->host_end_date' and alert_itsm_ack_status IS NULL";
            $details = NimsoftAlerts::model()->findAll($criteria);
            $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('NimsoftAlerts',array(
                'criteria'   => $criteria,));
        }
        else $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('NimsoftAlerts');
    //  if(isset($pagination))
    //  {
    //      $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('NimsoftAlerts',array(
    //          'criteria'   => $criteria,));
    //  }
    }
    else
    { $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('NimsoftAlerts'); }

    if($_REQUEST['isXLSDownload']=='1')
    {
        $xlsName='Missing_Host_Details_'.date('YmdHis').'.xls';
        $sheetName='Missing Host Details';
        $headerTxt='Host Details';
        $arrTh=array(
            'alert_device'=>array('label'=>'Alert Device'),
            'alert_event_time'=>array('label'=>'Alert Event Time'),
            'alert_datetime'=>array('label'=>'Alert Datetime'), 
        );
        $this->generateCXLS($xlsName,$sheetName,$criteria,$model,$headerTxt,$arrTh);
        //GlobalFuncs::generateCXLS($xlsName,$sheetName,$criteria,$model,$headerTxt,$arrTh);
    }

    $nimsoftAlerts = new NimsoftAlerts;
    $viewNimsoftTktSts = $nimsoftAlerts->dispNimsoftTktSts(); 
    // renders the view file 'protected/views/site/index.php'
    // using the default layout 'protected/views/layouts/main.php'
    $this->render('index',array(
        'viewNimsoftTktSts'=>$viewNimsoftTktSts,
        'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
        'model'=>$model,
    ));        
}
```

Comment: can anyone please help me in this?

Comment: no one there to give a solution for this?

Comment: please any suggestion on this topic?

Comment: any update for this, i have been waiting for your replies for hours

Answer (score 0):

On clicking the pagination buttons, this is what gets called - 

`$dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('NimsoftAlerts');` 

and not 

`if(isset($_POST['NimsoftAlerts'])) { [......] }`.

So try this -

```
$model=new NimsoftAlerts;
$model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values

//Removed the content from here.

if(isset($_POST['NimsoftAlerts'])) 
{
    $model->attributes=$_POST['NimsoftAlerts'];
    if($model->validate())
    {
        [.....]
    }
    else {
        $dataProvider = $model->search();
    }
}
else {
    $dataProvider = $model->search();
}
```

The `$model->search()` will add the filters and the pagination would include the filtered values received from `$_GET[]`.

I hope it helps.

Comment: what is $_GET['EmpAccount']?

Comment: Thanks for notifying it. Removed those lines.

Comment: I have added another answer that should give some insight on what is happening on form submit and pagination clicks. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the selected dates from your custom search form does not get send when the pagination is used and so all records are fetched. So you have to send them manually.

I have implemented the same scenario in my sample project. Try to resemble it in your project.

In your view file -

```
//Your form has datepicker, this form has a textbox. On submit the values are posted to apply the filter.
<form id="filter_form" method="POST">
    <input name="Skill[name]" id="Skill_name" value="<?php echo $model->name; ?>" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit_btn" id="submit_btn" value="Submit" />
</form>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.page a').click(function(ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
            $.fn.yiiGridView.update('skill-grid', {data: $('#filter_form').serialize()});       //This will include the values from the form (dates in your case)
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

In your controller-action -

```
$model = new Skill;
$model->unsetAttributes();

if(isset($_REQUEST['Skill'])) {
    $model->attributes = $_REQUEST['Skill'];
}
$dataProvider = $model->search();

$this->render('admin', array(
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'model' => $model,
));`
```

Important Note: Replace the 'Skill' Model name with 'NimsoftAlerts'.

I hope it helps.

Comment: here in the view, you have no Grid view?

Comment: I have just copied here some contents from my view file. Its not the complete answer, please change it according to your needs. Use the same Gridview code, your CActiveForm will at last create a similar form (use yours). If needed, will edit the answer later -  whole line to line code.